# I am building a VAR model and need help

Tags: r, forecasting, vector-autoregression

I wanted to make sure I do not mis-specify anything, so all challenge or recent econometric books/sources are welcome. I will be using R (and most probably the well established vars package)

**The model**

I have a definitive set of exogenous variables for which I will have expert forecasts for, up to h=3.

```
X1,...,X7
```

I have three endogenous variables, whose **forecasts** I am interested in for up to h=3. These forecasts will depend on the exogenous inputs for t+3.

```
Y1, Y2 & Y3.
```

Y1 and Y2 have a relatively strong correlation and Y3 is not strongly correlated to the other two.

Assuming data quality and quantity is a non-issue, what is the best VAR specification?

Is the VAR approach reasonable for this context?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The Y variables are corporate related financial metrics as reported in the year-end balance sheets. The X-exogenous variables are macroeconomic variables.

They are annual observations, and as a result I am somewhat constrained with regards to the data available.

Comment: As of now there is not enough information to tell what VAR specification is best. Without any extra knowledge, the recommendation would be to run a regularized VAR model including the exogenous variables and their lags up to some sensible maximum lag order. But what do your variables represent in reality? At what frequency are they sampled?

Comment: Thank you Richard. I am adding this detail on the edit above.

Comment: I suppose that limits the maximum number of lags to around two. Then maybe you can start with unregularized  (i.e. standard) VAR(1) or VAR(2) and see how it looks. But you could also use e.g. LASSO to kick out some variables as in the works of Barbaglia, Croux, Wilms and coauthors [here](http://feb.kuleuven.be/ines.wilms/software).

Comment: I have already eliminated a lot of those macroeconomic variables using lasso elastic net and even gibbs sampling. I have to draw the line on variable subset as I have dedicated a lot of time already.

Comment: So what do you suggest? That your goal is a VAR with the same lags for all variables (e.g. lags 1 and 2)? You can try that, people do that a lot.

Comment: Thank you for helping out Richard. I will limit the lags to two and still test for serial correlation. What is your recommendation if the test comes back unfavorable? I cannot increase the lag count nor reduce it effectively . On a related question, wouldn't the exogenous variables impact the error of the serial correlation?

Comment: When forecasting, you may tolerate some small autocorrelations if the AIC of the model beats that of a more complex model which eliminates the autocorrelations. Yes, exogenous variables would affect serial correlation.